# Malfunctioning input form in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a simple React App to input: a title, a list of sentences (number depending on the user).

This is my App.js code:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {useState} from 'react';
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { getFirestore, getDocs, collection, addDoc, deleteDoc, doc } from 'firebase/firestore'
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional

function App() {
  let total = 0;
  let [heading, setHead] = useState('');
  let [anslst, setAnslst] = useState(['']);
  let [swtch, setSwitch] = useState(true);

  function Headingbar(){
    return(
      <div className="head-rect padd">
        <div className="heading-div">
          <div className="side-text">FILL</div>
          <label className="switch">
            <input className="inputbox" type="checkbox" checked={!swtch} onChange={(e) => { setSwitch(!e.target.checked); }}/>
              <span className="slider round"></span>
          </label>
          <div className="side-text">VIEW</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  function Fill() {
    return (
      <>
        <form className="padd title-form">
          <input type="text" className="title-textbox textbox-defaults" placeholder="Title" onChange={(e) => { setHead(e.target.value) }} />
        </form>
        {
          anslst.map((i)=>{
            total += 1;
            return(
              <form className="padd answer-form">
                <textarea rows="10" cols="60" type="text" id={total - 1} className="answer-textbox textbox-defaults" placeholder="points" onChange={(e) => {
                  anslst[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
                  setAnslst(anslst);
                }} />
              </form>
            );
        })
        }
        <div className="bottom padd">
          <form>
            <input type="button" value="+" className="padd plus-button" onClick={()=>{
              anslst = [...anslst, ''];
              setAnslst(anslst);
              console.log(anslst);
            }}/>
          </form>
          <form>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick={()=>{add(heading, anslst)}}/>
          </form>
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Headingbar />
      {swtch && <Fill />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The main piece of code in focus is:

```
<form className="padd title-form">
          <input type="text" className="title-textbox textbox-defaults" placeholder="Title" onChange={(e) => { setHead(e.target.value) }} />
</form>
```

This form seems to malfunction ie on entering values into it , the cursor automatically disappears from the form. Sometimes randomly one of the letters is filled into the form before the cursor disappears.

I expected the form to take any input I give to it.

My debugging attempts:

1. When I remove the 'onChange' part of the input tag, it works as expected.
2. When I replace the function inside onChange with any function which doesn't use setHead function, the form works as expected.

This convinced me that the problem is with setHead() but I couldn't understand what.

Comment: You are re-creating the `Fill` component on each render, move it out of the `App` component, and pass the values/function via props.

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68999032/creating-react-functional-components-inside-other-components-or-in-a-separate-fi

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59776799/its-okay-to-declare-other-components-inside-a-component

Comment: Basically, the entire component is being unmounted and re-mounted, which is causing the focus to be lost and input to be unstable. The input is unstable because there is no `value` prop to hold the value between lifecycles. However the first problem is the more important

Comment: Thanks, guys the comments were helpful. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, ReactJS is a **one-way data binding**, so when you want to control the value yourself, you need to pass the attribute `value` for the input to make it controlled form field. Otherwise, the value you set (by `setHead()`) and the value it displayed is not matched (that's the malfunction you said).

That's why when you remove `setHead()`, it worked as expected (because the `<input/>` handle value itself, so the value displayed and the value of the input is the same one).

To fixed this, just add `value` for the `<input/>`.

```
<form className="padd title-form">
  <input type="text"
    className="title-textbox textbox-defaults"
    placeholder="Title"
    value={heading}
    onChange={(e) => { setHead(e.target.value) }}
  />
</form>
```

---

*Additional: **What is one-way data binding?***

In one-way binding, the data flow is **one-directional**. It means that: at a time, only one of the following conditions can be followed:

- ***Component to View:*** Any change in component data would get reflected in the view.
- ***View to Component:*** Any change in view would get reflected in the component’s data.

Here in your case, the *component data* is your state (`heading`) (because you call `setHead()` inside `onChange()` function), while there's nothing to display in view now (because the `<input/>` missed the `value` attribute).

You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519889/can-anyone-explain-the-difference-between-reacts-one-way-data-binding-and-angula) for more explanations about one-way binding & two-way binding, as it not really related to your question's topic.