# Can I lazy load in React by writing inline code?

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

I am trying to lazy load a component in React. It works if I declare the component at the top of the module. However it does not render anything if I declare it in a inline way.

Case 1 : Works as expected

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import { Routes, Link, Route, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import CaseStudies from "./pages/CaseStudies";

const ExampleAssembly = lazy(() => import("./pages/ExampleAssembly"));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/casestudies" element={<CaseStudies />} >
            <Route path="assembly" element={<ExampleAssembly />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
}
```

Case 2: Doesn't work

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import { Routes, Link, Route, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import CaseStudies from "./pages/CaseStudies";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/casestudies" element={<CaseStudies />} >
            <Route path="assembly" element={ lazy(() => {
              return import("./pages/ExampleAssembly");
            })  } />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
}
```

Is there a correct way to write inline lazy loaded components? Or should I always have lazy loaded component definitions at the top as in Case1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you should always load your component definitions at the top as in Case 1.

`lazy` is not designed to be used in the inline fashion that you describe. As the [React docs say](https://react.dev/reference/react/lazy):

> `lazy` returns a React component you can render in your tree

So, it's failing in Case 2 because you're using `lazy`'s return value as a function, rather than as a component, which is why React logs an error `Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child`.

You *could* use the return value with `createElement`, in which case it does actually render:

```js
            // WARNING: BAD IDEA, NOT FOR PRODUCTION USE
            <Route path="assembly" element={ 
              React.createElement(
                lazy(() => {
                  return import("./pages/ExampleAssembly");
                })
              )
            } />
```

This is, however, creating a new lazy component every time the `Route` is rendered. It's essentially the same as declaring a new component in a function scope, which is [a definite anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68999454/21146235), except it also involves a Promise that does network loading on every render. Just ... don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

Always do it like how you have it in case 1. You're trying to force a pattern that doesn't, and shouldn't, exist in the other example.